# Successfully added a Database Server but nothing inside (ArcCatalog)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm just a newbie in using ArcGIS. I'm trying to create a Web editing application in ArcGIS Server Manager like this post does [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISSERVER/9.3/DOTNET/index.htm#tutorial_web_editing_app.htm), but after added a Database Server i realize that there is nothing inside it, so i can't add User and add the SOC account :sad: Is there any way to fix it ?

[image]

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and ArcGIS Server Enterprise 10.0

Comment: A *Database Server* is a SQL-Server Express database.  By default, it is empty.  You'd need to add data to it before you could edit that data.  ArcGIS 10.0 has been in Retired support status since January, and the ArcGIS 9.3 from the example you are following has been Retired since the previous January.  ArcGIS Server was substantially changed at 10.1 (no more SOC), so the pool of folks familiar with the old way will be limited. Feature Services have superseded the web editing functionality you reference, and they require an Enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: Really thank you @Vince :) I'm newbie so i'm just follow the guides.